# How to resolve CPU bottleneck on sql server caused by high signal wait time (SOS_SCHEDULER_YIELD)?

Tags: sql-server

I'm monitoring CPUs on my sql server. The machine only has SQL server and no additional software other than anti-virus (with sql server file scan exclusions)

Server has about 60 databases. Of these about 20 are actively in use.

2 CPUs, each with 12 cores -> resulting in 4 soft-NUMA nodes with 6 cores

Max DOP 8

Cost threshold for parallelism 50

SSD disks

Server memory 128GB of which 100GB is assigned to sql server as Max mem setting. Entire 100GB is utilized.

Each CPU (via perf mon) is showing utilization of 80% to 100% between 8am to 5pm. And between 2am to 4am. These are the times when the users are actively using the application or when nightly stored procedures are running. At other times the utilization is anywhere from 30% to 100%.

Query optimization is not possible as that software is maintained by 3rd party.

Each thread gets 4ms processor time after which it has to yield into the runnable queue. Or it is waiting for resource then thread has to yield into waiting queue.

```
+──────────────────────+──────────────────+──────────────+─────────────+─────────────+───────────+───────────────+─────────────+─────────────+───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────+
| WaitType             | Wait Percentage  | AvgWait_Sec  | AvgRes_Sec  | AvgSig_Sec  | Wait_Sec  | Resource_Sec  | Signal_Sec  | Wait Count  | Help/Info URL                                             |
+──────────────────────+──────────────────+──────────────+─────────────+─────────────+───────────+───────────────+─────────────+─────────────+───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────+
| SOS_SCHEDULER_YIELD  | 1.43             | 0.0005       | 0           | 0.0005      | 156834.61 | 229.11        | 156605.5   | 291900201   | https://www.sqlskills.com/help/waits/SOS_SCHEDULER_YIELD  |
+──────────────────────+──────────────────+──────────────+─────────────+─────────────+───────────+───────────────+─────────────+─────────────+───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────+
```

Signal_Sec is much higher than Resource_Sec - this means that waits are not due to resource issues, but due to large number of threads that are waiting on the CPU  (runnable queue).

1. Does 1.43% wait percentage mean this is negligible?
2. Irrespective of the above answer I would like to know whether this (high signal wait time) suggests that I must add more CPUs or increase the power of existing CPUs?
3. Will action taken in point 2 help to keep the CPU usage of upto 90% so that the CPUs aren't constantly at 100% or is this (CPU 100%) something to not worry about?

Comment: You should run `sp_BlitzFirst @ExpertMode = 1, @SinceStartup = 1` (from the [First Responder Kit](https://www.brentozar.com/responder)) to identify your actual top waits and post the results. `SOS_SCHEDULER_YIELD` isn't always a bad thing, but it can sometimes indicate CPU pressure. During the heavy load timeframes, did you check that every core is evenly heavily utilized, or is it only some of the cores hitting 100%? You can also use `sp_BlitzCache @SortOrder = 'cpu'` and `sp_BlitzIndex` to determine tuning opportunities without necessarily altering queries.

Answer (score 2):

> Does 1.43% wait percentage mean this is negligible?

It depends on what the other waits are, and how they're distributed.  It may be a very big deal only sometimes, or it may be a consistent small contributor to the overall user waits.

> Irrespective of the above answer I would like to know whether this (high signal wait time) suggests that I must add more CPUs or increase the power of existing CPUs?

Yes. High SOS_SCHEDULER_YIELD wait time and Signal Wait time on other resource waits indicates that more CPU resources would improve the workload throughput.

> is this (CPU 100%) something to not worry about?

It means that you're using all the CPU resources you paid for, but the applciations are waiting on the database server.